# Filter gridview data with one row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting records from three tables in grid-view.

Here two table data is always the same but one table data shows different records I want to show third table data in one row in grid-view, when third table data gets the record then it needs to be filtered with comma separated using c#.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make custom datatable acoording to your need, and bind the datatable  to gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You can store return result in a list and filter it before bind to grid.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the union in your query to avoid the duplicate records rather than doing after binding the records.

You may get 50 records from the database but after removing the duplicates you may have just 5 to 10 records so why you want to get the 50 records, why can't remove them at the time of querying them.

Use something like this:

```
select x, y, z from Table1
Union
select x, y, z from Table2    
Union
select x, y, z from Table3
```

It will always give you the ditinct records.